# Is it Possible to Style a Disabled INPUT element with CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

I need to style  *`disabled`* `<select>`elements to make them look like they're enabled. Can someone help?

PS. I am all-too-aware of the downsides of doing this sort of thing vis a vis HCI principles etc., but its a requirement so I've got to do it if it is possible ...

Thanks.

EDIT:

@AlexThomas' method works well when the elements are disabled in HTML code but unfortunately I'm doing the disabling/enabling with JQuery:

```
<select class='dayselector'>
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
    <!-- .... etc. -->
</select>

$(".dayselector").attr("disabled",true);

$(".dayselector").attr("disabled",false);
```

So the selector:

```
$(".dayselector")  //works and gets all the selects
```

and

```
$(".dayselector option")  //works and gets all the selects' option items
```

but
    `$(".dayselector [disabled='true']")  //doesn't return anything.`

and

```
`$(".dayselector [disabled='false']")  //doesn't return anything.
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using jquery:

```
$('option[disabled="true"]').each(function () {
                 $(this).attr('style', 'color:red');
});
```

check it in action here [http://jsfiddle.net/GfNve](http://jsfiddle.net/GfNve/3)

Comment: You Sir are a &star;!  I only wish I could give you more votes :-)

Many thanks, looks ace!

Comment: Damn it. It works well when the elements are disabled declaratively in HTML but not when they're disabled via JQuery which is what I'm doing. Please see edit above - would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: When you set the disable in jquery also set the style.

Comment: Ser-weeet! Many thanks :-) I'm not entirely sure why this makes a difference, but who cares, its working nicely.

Comment: $('option:disabled').attr('style', 'color:red');​

Answer (score 10):

You could either go with

```
select[disabled] {  }
```

(not supported in <IE7)

**or**

```
select:disabled {  }
```

(not supported in <IE9)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should use `readonly` instead of `disabled`. This will make the input enabled, but without allowing the user to change its value.

Comment: I suggested this, but the field needs to be uneditable directly - instead there are 'master' controls which set them.

Comment: Aren't those master controls able to set readonly instead of disabled? :)

Comment: I repeat: 

I don't want the selects to be editable directly. So readonly won't do it as they will remain changeable.

Comment: How are they changable if they are readonly? Readonly means uneditable.

Comment: @GolezTrol - here's what I mean, they're readonly but you can still select a different element so they're CHANGEABLE: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/KG6us/

Comment: Ah I see. Select doesn't support readonly. Readonly is only for other input field. So they're *not* readonly.

Comment: In addition to select, checkbox also does not support read-only.

Comment: @smclark89 Thanks for the downvote, but neither the question nor my answer is about checkboxes.

Comment: But, it was about selects. The tidbit about checkboxes is free loot for anyone who reads the comments. The downvote is because this answer is flat out wrong.