# Issue with disable button not looking disabled in Mozilla

Tags: asp.net, css, mozilla

We have asp.net button and we disable them based on user permission. Sample code is

```
btnSave.Enabled = false;
```

The button is disabled and hence non-clickable in IE.
However in Mozilla the button looks enabled , though the user cannot click it.

Machine OS: Windows 7
IE version : 8.0
Mozilla version:Mozilla/5.0

Any workarounds or solution for this , or why is it behaving this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use CSS to resolve this issue.

```
button[disabled] {
 background-color: #ddd;
/* Add CSS here for disable button look and feel*/
}
```

Comment: But that will require me to do a lot of changes across application in multiple pages. Anything generic is not possible.

Comment: No, you will not need to make any change, just add this css and it will implmented automatically on disabled button.

Comment: This worked great for me!  I changed it to input[disabled]{ /* code here*/ } ... I did have to include !important so it would work in IE, but that might have just been bad CSS on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens. To overcome this issue, you should write a CSS class and apply it when it is enable or disable. 
For Ex.

```
.enable
{
color:black;
}

.disable
{
color:#333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question a few months ago. You might find the responses useful: [Is it Possible to Style a Disabled INPUT element with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043051/is-it-possible-to-style-a-disabled-input-element-with-css/5043124#comment-5723908)